# Powershell script providing false positives (Exchange Online)

Tags: powershell, automation

I seem to be coming across issues with a check i have put in place to confirm a mailbox has ben converted from a users mailbox to shared mailbox.

```
Connect-ExchangeOnline -UserPrincipalName $UserCredential.UserName
Write-Host "checking mailbox has converted to a shared mailbox...."
$Mailboxcheck = Get-Mailbox "$username" | select isshared
if ($Mailboxcheck.IsShared -eq $False) {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Mailbox for $($username) has NOT been converted to shared, please confirm.")
} else {
    [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Mailbox for $($username) has been converted to shared.")
}
```

the issue is sometimes this check will work and other times it won't (randomly). So we convert the mailbox to a shared mailbox via the above script then the check will sometimes come up as the $False message rather then the else message but when we go to manually check it after it's run the mailbox has been converted to shared.

The only things i can think of is to add the disconnect and reconnect to exchange online in case it's due to some syncing time, Possibly add a Start-sleep to the script to give it more time to sync, or its to do with the if statement and the variable $false as $mailboxcheck.isshared should only provide a value of "True" or "False"

```
if ($Mailboxcheck.IsShared -eq $False)
```

Another way i have made the script to check is with a switch statement but am unsure if that will be me any benefit and unsure if it's the right use case or should stick to the if statement

```
$Mailboxcheck = Get-Mailbox "$username" | select isshared
switch ($Mailboxcheck.isshared)
{
    True {[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Mailbox for $($username) has been converted to shared."); Break}

    False {[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Mailbox for $($username) has NOT been converted to shared, please confirm."); Break}

    default {[System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show("Unable to check mailbox type for $($username). Please confirm it has been converted to shared.")}
}
```

Let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code along side the other one to see when the IsShared property actually changes:

```
$repeat = $true
do
{
    $Mailboxcheck = Get-Mailbox "$username"
    Write-Host "Date =                   $(get-date)" -for Green
    write-host "RecipientTypeDetails =   $($Mailboxcheck.RecipientTypeDetails)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    write-host "IsShared =               $($Mailboxcheck.isShared)" -ForegroundColor yellow
    ""
    sleep 10

}
while ($repeat -eq $true)
```

Comment: Thanks Judd, i have run this in Parallel with the script and have found out it has been taking anywhere from 10 - 20 seconds for it to update, i have added a buffer of 40 seconds before the check is started and will see in the future if it provides any false positives.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Its a pleasure. Would you mind v0ting my answer "up" if you found it useful. :)